# python unexpected null in string.isalpha()

Tags: python

function should change sentence to list of words separated by space and than checks if there are 3 words in a row containing only letters

```
def words(str):
slowa = str.split(str)
if len(slowa) < 2:
    return 0
else:
    for x in range(2,len(slowa)):
        if slowa[x].isalpha() and slowa[x-1].isalpha() and slowa[x-2].isalpha():
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

fe: words("one one one") returns true

but words("one one 1 one one one 1 one one 1 one one 1") returns false.
Any tips why this happens?

Comment: Because you return `0` on the first test in the loop. The loop exits with a `return`, you never tested the rest of your list. `"one one 1"` is not a match, you need to continue looping until you find the `"one one one"` sequence later on.

Answer (score 1):

Because you return `0` on the first failed test in your loop. The loop exits with a `return`, you never tested the rest of your list. `"one one 1"` is not a match, you need to continue looping until you find the `"one one one"` sequence later on.

Move the `return 0` to *after* the `for` loop, only when you have tested all positions do you know for sure there is nothing matching:

```
for x in range(2,len(slowa)):
    if slowa[x].isalpha() and slowa[x-1].isalpha() and slowa[x-2].isalpha():
        return 1

return 0
```

Note that your test for the length is redundant; the `range()` will simply be empty for shorter sequences:

```
def words(inputstring):
    slowa = inputstring.split()
    for x in range(2, len(slowa)):
        if slowa[x].isalpha() and slowa[x-1].isalpha() and slowa[x-2].isalpha():
            return 1
    return 0
```